# How do I style the "no file chosen" tooltip for file upload buttons in order to position it below the button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, upload, tooltip

I have managed to remove the tooltip entirely, just to see if it was possible to style this tooltip, in any way. But what I actually need is to position it centred below the choose file button.
The CSS for getting rid of the tool tip was basically this:

```
input[type="file"] {
display: none;
}
```

Which basically results in the button looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTtay.png)

However, if I remove the css, I am left with [this mad button inside of a button mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsmBW.png) which includes the tooltip inside the button

To be clear, both the button and the button within the button do the same thing. I am not 100% clear on why it displays like it as this is my first time working with a file upload button which isn't my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Followed by this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/cvnCt) you can simply do it like this:

```
<html>
<style>
.custom-file-input {
  color: transparent;
}
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Select some files';
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.custom-file-input:active {
  outline: 0;
}
.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9); 
}
</style>
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" />
</html>
```

Now the question is how it works?
To get the answer know about css ::before selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)

Hope this helps!